# Are screen printing questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

In regards to the recent question: [How do I deturmine exposure time for a silk screen?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13576/how-do-i-deturmine-exposure-time-for-a-silk-screen)

Is this considered on topic? There was no screen-printing tag, so I created one. I searched for any screen-printing related questions asked previously and found this one: [Will 300 dpi (non-vector) result in blurry artwork for screen printing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4825/will-300-dpi-non-vector-result-in-blurry-artwork-for-screen-printing)

Answer (score 1):

I think the **resolution question is applicable** because it relates to file creation and design.

I think the **exposure question is off-topic** because it refers to steps in an output processes unrelated to file creation, much the same way "How do I use split-well printing on my press?" or "What is a good direct to plate imagesetter?" would be off topic.

But, this is just my opinion... and I have no power :)

Comment: I agree with this reasoning